# How to fill a dataframe from a function in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to update the iris data frame.

```
raw <- iris

function(){
  assign("raw$Sepal.Length[23]", 7.2, envir = globalenv())  
}

View(raw)
```

But this is not working even though I have used assign.

Comment: Usually you want to avoid using `assign()` to the global environment. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have a function that transforms a data frame, but it is not working cause my data frame is in a different environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you want to avoid using `assign()` or `<<-` to the global environment. In this case you can use ``<<-` to do deep assignment if the data frame is in your search path.

```
raw<-iris
myfun <- function(){
  raw$Sepal.Length[23] <<- 7.2
  NULL
}
myfun()
raw$Sepal.Length[23]
```